# On Trello, how do I get emails to send with the correct timezone?

Tags: trello

On Trello, my local time zone seems to have been set. However, when I get reminder emails as a deadline approaches, the time zone is different. Is there a way to set the notification email's time zone to that of the individual members? In my case I am trying to coordinate with a fellow in a different time zone.